# How to go about updating modular visualizations

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm helping guide a project that's combining some visualizations in D3. In our specific example we are producing a graph of pies by using a regular D3 Pie chart with the sankey layout visualization. The affect of this is to produce something like:

[image]

The development is aimed to try and keep this as modular as possible, therefore the very first step was to produce an updating pie chart that could be used stand alone or plugged into another visualization. This is currently encapuslated into a `pieObject` which looks something like this:

```
var pieObject = function( d, target ){
   var pie = {}; 
   // other code to handle init

   pie.update = function(data) {
      // render code
   };
};
```

Where it gets a little confusion is in the tree visualization, when I need to start handling updates. Here is how a new pie is added:

```
sankey.nodes(data.nodes)
      .links(data.links)
      .layout(32);

var node = svg.append("g")
    .selectAll(".node")
    .data(data.nodes)
    .enter() 
    .append("g")
    .attr("class", "node")
    .attr("transform", function (d) { return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")"; });
    .each( function( d ) {
        var pie = new pieObject( d, this );
    })
```

If I however want to deal with an existing node, I'm not sure how I should go about accessing the `pieObject`? There are a couple of options I can think of, but I'm wondering if there's a general approach commonly used?

1. Store the pieObject on the element `d`
2. Store the pieObject in an array or JavaScript object with a lookup from a field on the `d`

Out of the examples I've outlined, I prefer option #1. But I'm also re-loading my entire data-set from JSON (e.g. new JSON request returns existing data + new data) so I believe when I call `sankey.nodes(data.nodes).links(data.links).layout(32);` that this is going to lose any additional information I've stored on the `d` object?

**EDIT**

I've put together a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/IPWright83/1do29p2b/) to help illustrate my problem. The code is a little lengthy and I don't own it as yet so don't know all the ins & outs but here's a breakdown:

- ## 1-#214 - Sankey code which produces the Tree layout
- ## 215-#451 - Code for a Pie Chart
- ## 453-#475 - Code to add the viz to the page

Specifically the area of creating the pies, and trying to figure out how to update them is in the render function between lines #129-#149

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend starting with Mike Bostock's tutorial on re-usable charts, which does pretty much what you are looking for: http://bost.ocks.org/mike/chart/

Specifically, the key to this type of thing is to use the selection.call() function to insert your chart into another chart/layout in a re-usable way. Then when you need to update your embedded chart, just do the same selection.call() again. Hopefully that gets you started.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Ethan, I've read that article before but have just re-read + the documentation for `selection.call()` and I still don't quite understand what you're suggesting. Could you elaborate a little bit, maybe with a code sample?

Comment: I think you need to switch from using .each(... new pieObject ...) to using .call(pieChart) where pieChart is a function taking a selection like in the article. Within your pieChart function, figure out if you've already instantiated the chart by checking the contents of the selection. If you haven't instantiated yet, do your initialization work and if you have instantiated, do your update. If you'd like to put together a minimal JSFiddle or similar example, I'd be happy to try to update it.

Comment: I think I kinda follow, but I've got another question I need a JSFiddle for (that's kinda related) so I might as well include that too. Probably take me a little while, but I'll update and comment to let you know. Thanks

Comment: Ethan - I've added a link to my original post and a few comments on where important bits of code are...

Comment: Here's a start: http://jsfiddle.net/zuwur218/1/  It doesn't work properly and I didn't try to update to use call instead of each, but may give you some ideas to get started. I'd recommend going back and starting from scratch with a more basic version of what you're trying to do and build back up slowly. Having a more basic version will also help with getting answers here.